# Are "AT MY peril" and "TO MY peril" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm considering simple one-liners which help describe scenarios in statistical hypothesis testing.  Some of you may perhaps be familiar with the concept of Type 2 errors (the cost of ignoring a false null hypothesis).

I wanted to describe Type 2 errors using the following sentence:

> I ignore this possibility ***to** my peril.*

That's when I got confused as to whether I should say "to my peril" or "at my peril".

Searching on Google, I noticed hardly any examples using "to my peril" in a sentence.  Almost all were second person references: "at your peril..." which sounds familiar and comfortable.

There's [this link](https://ludwig.guru/s/at+my+peril) which uses "at my peril", but somehow, it sounds very awkward.  It may very well be correct usage, however.  Can anybody clarify?

Comment: Why does it sound awkward?

Comment: Usually *at your peril* is a warning or admonishment to others. I don't need it! So I don't warn myself at my peril.

Comment: *at* is the right preposition, but *at my **own** peril* will work better.

Comment: "to my peril" is definitely wrong.

Comment: Although language is not democratic, "at" is more frequent than "to". Google Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+my+peril%2Cto+my+peril%2Cat+your+peril%2Cto+your+peril%2Cat+their+peril%2Cto+their+peril&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3